# SPFX Angular Element with UI-Router not displaying data

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, angularjs

Iam testing Angular Element with SharePoint Framework (SPFX) Webpart, as Andrew Conell has described in his [Blog](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/howto-angular-elements-in-sharepoint-framework-projects-two-projects)

Every thing is working as asspected, i have added UI-Router in webpart just for testing how it works with Angular Element inside SPFX webpart. And as asspected routing is working, but no data is displayed on the MainComponent (Main page). I have added some test data in main.component.ts as below:

`public data: any[];
    public heroes = [
      {id: 1, name:'Superman'},
      {id: 2, name:'Batman'},
      {id: 5, name:'BatGirl'},
      {id: 3, name:'Robin'},
      {id: 4, name:'Flash'}
    ];
    public test:string;

```
constructor(){
  let t = "main page...";
  this.test = t;
  this.data = this.heroes;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));
}
```

`

And in main.component.html:

`<span>{{test}}</span>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Index</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let hero of data">
            <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`

And if i add same test data in my AppComponent then it works, data in table get displayed and even text string "test" is dislayed...

Here is my solution (SPFXAngularUIRouter) on [GITHUB](https://github.com/gonadn/SPFXAngularUIRouter) for testing...

I think i have same problom as described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209510/angular-2-routing-in-sharepoint-framework-spfx)